# TypeError when using botocore to read from AWS SQS queue

Tags: python-2.7, tornado, amazon-sqs, botocore

I'm using a Tornado server with tornado-botocore to connect to Amazon SQS services.
When running stress tests we sometimes get the following exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/app/handlers/WebSocketsHandler.py", line 95, in listen_outgoing_queue
>
> message = yield tornado.gen.Task(self.outgoing_queue.read)
>
> File "/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 870, in run
>       value = future.result()
>
> File "/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 215, in result
>       raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
>
> File "/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 314, in wrapped
>       ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado_botocore/base.py", line 70, in prepare_response
>       response_dict, operation_model.output_shape)
>
> File "/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 155, in parse
>       return self._do_error_parse(response, shape)
>
> File "/home/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 314, in _do_error_parse
>       root = self._parse_xml_string_to_dom(xml_contents)
>
> File "/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 274, in _parse_xml_string_to_dom
>       parser.feed(xml_string)
>
> TypeError: must be string or read-only buffer, not None

could it be caused by the concurrency?
has anyone encountered such behavior?

We are using tornado 4.2.1, botocore 0.65.0 and tonado-botocore 0.1.6

Comment: Please post the code that raised this exception, so that others can help you, and so that this question might help someone else who finds it.

Answer (score -2):

problem solved once i removed the @tornado.gen.engine decorator from the method